# Create a select list of users in Bash on OS X

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to create a copy script to quickly copy a user folder in OS X, while excluding all the junk (caches, old iPhone Backups, logs, etc.). As far as not copying those files/folders I am not having a problem. The problem is when selecting the user. I want to build a list of all the users on the computer, excluding system accounts, and have the operator choose which user folder to backup by just typing a number from a list. Currently I can get the users with the following command:

```
userList=`dscl . list /Users UniqueID | awk '$2 >= 400 { print $1; }'`
```

For example, this will return:

```
hiddenadmin fred joe kim
```

I would like to create a select list that then shows:

```
Please choose which user folder you would like to copy:
  1) hiddenadmin
  2) fred
  3) joe
  4) kim
```

Once I have the user I am fine, but I cannot seem to get the list to create. Also, the there is no guarantee that the names would be the same, or even the number of users would be the same.

In case you are wondering why I don't just look in the /Users folder to create the list. Some accounts may be hidden and have their user folder elsewhere, and I don't want the `Guest` or `Shared` folders in the list. The problem here is that I don't even know where to start on this one.

Answer (score 0):

There are **a lot** of ways to do what you're asking. Here's my quick and dirty take.

Since you already have your users in a variable, you just need a `for` loop to do your formatting. I'll use your values for my example:T

```
userList="hiddenadmin fred joe kim"
echo "Please choose which user folder you would like to copy:"
count=0
for name in $userList;do
  count=$((count+1))
  printf '\t%s) %s\n' $count $name
  echo
done
read -p "Choose from $(eval echo {1..$count}): " CHOICE
```

This loop will read your `userList`, initialize a counter and use `printf` for the output. The `\t` will indent your selections and `\n` sends a CRLF.

Once your menu option is printed, the `read` command will prompt the user for input and set their selection to the variable `CHOICE`. You can re-use the `count` variable within the `-p` option of `read` to display valid choices. You'll have to add some additional code to validate the input. You can do that with a simple `case` statement.

```
case $choice in 
  1) #some code
     ;;
  2) #some code
     ;;
  *) echo "Invalid choice"
     ;;
esac
```